# Passing a FILE pointer to a function and getting error message 'FILE is an unknown type name'

Tags: c, file-pointer

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a function, but my compiler throws an error saying that 'FILE is an unknown type name'.

In main:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
get_tok(fp);
```

Function declaration throws the error:

```
int get_tok(FILE *fp)
```

Am I not including a .h file or something?

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't have included `<stdio.h>` before you wrote the code mentioning `FILE *`.  If you had, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: most likely you included <stdio.h> in your main and not in the file where you declared your function in.

Comment: Incidentally, note that `fp` is a `FILE *`, not a function pointer.  You are only trying to pass a `FILE *` (a `FILE` pointer) to a function.

Comment: You did not include the file `stdio.h` from the compiler's directory. Add `#include <stdio.h>` and verify that you have no other file with that name in the search path.

Comment: WHAT error does the compiler casts?

Comment: Connor, we are going to presume that you looked at the top of the file containing `int get_tok(FILE *fp)` and found no `#include <stdio.h>` in its include chain and that you have since added it and the problem is solved. If not, drop another comment of post what you learned after reading [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

The best way is not to open the file outside the function..declare a file pointer. And inside the function,  use fopen and if the return value is 0 or null then return 0 or else return 1..and then read the returning value from main yo decide of the file has been opened successfully..